# Extract Craft CMS data to Vue component

Tags: vue

I want to extract data from Craft to a Vue component.

I create a vue component like this:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('homepage').first() %}
<template>
  <h1>{{entry}}</h1>
</template>
```

When I run the app it doesn't show the value of entry, but I created a file `title.twig` like this and it works:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('homepage').first() %}

<h1>{{ entry }}</h1>
```

In vue project I added this line `Vue.config.delimiters = ["${", "}"];`in main.js file and I added`index.twig` file to `templates/` like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I retrieve data directly from the Vue component? Thanks!

Comment: There's an article here that might be helpful for you: https://nystudio107.com/blog/using-vuejs-2-0-with-craft-cms

Comment: I read this article but, I didn't understand if I can use in a file like` homepage.vue` from an vue.js project

Comment: Are you using Vue version 1 or 2?

Comment: I use Vue version 2